# Changing colors of specific entries

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Can you change the circle color of specific entries when adding data to a set? Right now, I have two data sets that make two separate different colored lines. I want one line with different colored circles if that is possible.

Comment: please improve your question.. provide more info. like what you tried so far your ui screen shot and what you want (screen shot of what you want will help alot in this case)

Comment: SO is not a solution provider platform. It helps someone who is stuck to implement something and guide if someone lost right path.